# deserialize integer as boolean asp.net javascriptserializer

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, serialization

I am developing a mobile application which serializes a class containing a couple of boolean properties.
It treats boolean properties as integers, hence serializes them as "0" or "1".

On server side (ASP.NET Web Service), JavascriptSerializer tries to convert "0" to boolean, and gives Error: "0 is not a valid value for Boolean"

I need to modify javascript serializer so that when it encounters a "0" or "1" and expects a boolean, it converts their corresponding value to bool.

I investigated JavascriptConverter abstract class but did not help. Could you support with such a working example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its better converting true to 1 after Serialization.

Use some wrapper class or custom code